# Price a forward contract on a zero-coupon bond

Tags: option-pricing, forward

I'm trying to calculate the price of a forward contract on a zero-coupon bond (ZCB).  The forward contract matures at $t_1$ and the ZCB matures at $t_2$.  So is the price of the forwards contract just the ratio of (price ZCB that matures at $t_2$) / (price ZCB that matures at $t_1$) ?

Comment: Yes. Think about how you would replicate the forward contract by trading in the two zero bonds.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to obtain this result is, as I mentioned in the comment, to think about how you would replicate the forward contract. It has the following cash-flow structure:

```
 type          | t                  | t1                      | t2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 forward       | 0                  | +P(t1, t2) - K          | 0
```

Here, I also use $P(t_1, t_2)$ to denote the time $t_1$ price of the zero coupon bond with maturity in $t_2$. $K$ is the fair delivery price of the forward contract.

You replicate this contract by taking a long position in the zero-coupon with maturity $t_2$ and financing the purchase by selling the zero coupon bond with maturity in $t_1$ for a notional that yields a current cash-inflow of $P(t, t_2)$. You get

```
 type          | t                  | t1                      | t2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 long ZCB t2   | -P(t, t2)          | +P(t1, t2)              | 0
 short ZCB t1  | +P(t, t2)          | -P(t, t2) / P(t, t1)    | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 total         | 0                  | +P(t1, t2)              | 0
               |                    | -P(t, t2) / P(t, t1)    |
```

The portfolio has the same cash-flows as the forward in both $t$ and $t_2$. It has the same random cash-flow in $t_1$ ($+P(t_1, t_2)$) and thus the non-random cash-flows at this time also have to agree, i.e. $K = P(t, t_2) / P(t, t_1)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be $1$ at $t_2$ for the forward as well as for the long ZCB $t_2$ ?

Comment: No - that's all fine. Don't understand  your question regarding the forward but the position in the zero coupon bond is unwound upon the maturity of the forward contract - so there are no more cash-flows in $t_2$.

Comment: I am saying that long ZCB t2 gives you +1 at t2, that you don't take in account. And that should modify what is happeing at t2 for the forward as well, to be still able to apply your non arbitrage argument.

Comment: As I wrote before, the position in the zero bond is unwound in $t_1$. Thus, even though the zero bond has a cash-flow in $t_2$ of one, it is not relevant to this argument. Everything is correct here.

Comment: (Sorry for the delay, I just realized while browsing through old stuff that I forgot to answer.) At t for the long-short position it's not -P(t,t2)+P(t,t2) but -P(t,t2)+P(t,t1) and this is not 0 in general and hence as not the same cashflows at t=0 than the foward zero-coupon position. The correct idea is to be at t long a zc expiring at t2 and short a quantity P(t,t2)/P(t,t1) of zc's expiring at t1. This indeed cost 0 at t etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E^{t_1}$ be the expectation operator under the $t_1$-forwad probability measure $Q^{t_1}$, which takes the bond price process $\{P(t, t_1), \, 0\le t \le t_1\}$ as the numeraire. Then, the price of the forward contract, at time $t$, where $0\le t \le t_1$, is given by
\begin{align*}
E^{t_1}\big(P(t_1, t_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_t\big) &= E^{t_1}\left(\frac{P(t_1, t_2)}{P(t_1, t_1)}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&=\frac{P(t, t_2)}{P(t, t_1)},
\end{align*}
as $\left\{\frac{P(t, t_2)}{P(t, t_1)},  0\le t \le t_1\right\}$ is a martingale under the $t_1$-forwad probability measure $Q^{t_1}$. Here, $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set at time $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I'm not sure if I was calculating the (price ZCB that matures at t2t2) correctly.  When the I calculated (price ZCB that matures at t2t2) / (price ZCB that matures at t1t1)  I got a ratio of like 1.5.  What seemed to work was multiplying the strike times the forwards contract divided by the price that matures at t1.  So like K*F(t2)/P(t1)  I'm sorry if my notation is terrible.

Comment: The price is given by the answer.

Comment: @Gordon I have question that, if it is a ZCB, so the yield of forward bond price FBP is exactly the same as forward rate? If it's not a ZCB, they are not always same? Suppose we have the relation $$B(t_1,t_2) = G(y_{t_1}),$$ $y_{t_1}$ is the yield of $B(t_1,t_2)$ at $t_1,$  then we have $\textrm{FBP} _0 = G(y_0).$ Is it right?

Comment: @A.Oreo: I will say yes to both.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Gordon's answer. Denoting with $P(t,T,S)$ the $T$-forward price of a zero-coupon bond maturing in $S$  ($S \geq T$), we have the relation:

$$
P(t,T) P(t,T,S) = P(t,S)
$$

which, in terms of spot ($L$) and forward ($F$) simply-compounded yields, which are related by the relation:

$$
(1+\tau(t,T) L(t,T))(1+\tau(T,S)F(t,T,S))=(1+\tau(t,S)L(t,S)) 
$$

from which the standard forward yield, defined as the (see e.g., [Brigo-Mercurio (2001) chap 1](https://www.amazon.it/Interest-Rate-Models-Theory-Practice/dp/3540417729)

$$
F(t,T,S) = \frac{1}{\tau(T,S)} \left(\frac{P(t,T)}{P(t,S)} - 1\right)
$$

can be interpreted as the appropriate yield matching the forward price of a zcb

$$
P(t,T,S) = \frac{1}{1+ \tau(T,S) F(t,T,S)}
$$

where $\tau(x,y)$ is the time measure between times $x$ and $y$.