# forward contract on a defaultable zero-coupon bond

Tags: bond, forward, default-risk

I'am trying to calculate the price of a forward on a defaultable  zero-coupon bond. It is also true that the price will be given by [Price a forward contract on a zero-coupon bond](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32273/price-a-forward-contract-on-a-zero-coupon-bond) ? I guess the defautability of the bond shoud result in higher price for the forward than in the standard case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on notations in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/value-price-of-defaultable-zero-coupon-bond-with-credit-risk-involved/55157#55157), assuming the market value recovery mechanism, the pre-default value at time $T_1$ of a zero-coupon bond with maturity $T_2$, where $T_1 < T_2$, is given by
\begin{align*}
P(T_1, T_2) = E\Big(e^{-\int_{T_1}^{T_2}(r_s +(1-R)h_s)ds}\,\big|\, \mathscr{F}_{T_1}\Big).
\end{align*}
Let $B_t=e^{\int_0^t r_s ds}$ be the credit risk free money-market account value at time $t$.  The pre-default forward price $K$ determined at time $t$, for $0\le t \le T_1$, is a value such that
\begin{align*}
0 &= E\Big(\pmb{1}_{\tau>T_1}\frac{B_t}{B_{T_1}}(K-P(T_1, T_2)) \,|\,\mathscr{G}_t\Big)\\
&=\pmb{1}_{\tau>t}E\left(\Big(K e^{-\int_t^{T_1}(r_s+h_s) ds} - e^{-\int_t^{T_1}(r_s+h_s) ds-\int_{T_1}^{T_2}(r_s +(1-R)h_s)ds} \Big) \,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\right)\\
&=\pmb{1}_{\tau>t}E\left(\Big(K e^{-\int_t^{T_1}(r_s+h_s) ds} - e^{-\int_t^{T_2}(r_s+h_s) ds+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}Rh_sds} \Big) \,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
K = \frac{E\Big(e^{-\int_t^{T_2}(r_s+h_s) ds+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}Rh_sds} \,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\Big)}{E\Big(e^{-\int_t^{T_1}(r_s+h_s) ds} \,|\,\mathscr{F}_t\Big)}.
\end{align*}

Your observation appears correct if you assume that the interest rate is defined by $r_t+h_t$ in the standard case.

Comment: Always the best answers @Gordon.

Comment: Shouldn't the second expectation be conditional on $\mathscr{G}_t$? Thanks.

Comment: @ir7: Yes. Thanks for pointing out. The next step is based on the filtration switching formula.

Comment: @Gordon could you pls generalize to the case of coupon bearing bond ?

Comment: It is possible: you treat each coupon as a zero-coupon bond. If needed, please ask as another question, so that more people can participate.